# How do I execute a SPARQL update on a Sesame RDF repository from PHP?

Tags: php, insert, sparql, sesame

Hello I have a problems with insert data in php language. I'm using library sparqllib.php to connect and using sparql in php. I want to insert something. I'm trying this:

```
sparql_ns( "dc","http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" );   
    $sparql = "INSERT DATA{ <http://example/authorsID>  
              dc:written    '".$paper."' ;
              dc:label  '".$paper."'.}";
    $result = sparql_query( $sparql ); 
    if( !$result ) { print sparql_errno() . ": " . sparql_error(). "\n"; exit; }
    else {
        print_r ($result);
    }
```

But it doesn't work... It give me this output:

400: Bad response, 400: MALFORMED QUERY: Encountered " "insert" "INSERT "" at line 2, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    "base" ...
    "prefix" ...
    "select" ...
    "construct" ...
    "describe" ...
    "ask" ...

When I'm using this SPARQL in Repository - SPARQL Update:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
INSERT DATA
{ <http://example/authorsID>    dc:written    "paperID" ;
                        dc:label  "A.N.Other" .
}
```

then it works... I don't know how to fix it... Any ideas? I want to insert triple in format: name-has written-paper...

Comment: How do you initialize the connection to your Sesame repository?

Comment: $db = sparql_connect( "http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/bp" );

Answer (score 2):

The library you're using to connect to Sesame incorrectly assumes that the SPARQL endpoint for queries is the same as the endpoint for updates. This is not the case. In Sesame Server, the *query* endpoint is:

```
http://<host>:<port>/openrdf-sesame/repositories/<repositoryId>
```

But the *update* endpoint is:

```
http://<host>:<port>/openrdf-sesame/repositories/<repositoryId>/statements
```

You will need to find out if there is a way to set a separate update endpoint URL in that library. If there is not, it may also indicate that the PHP library you're trying to use is simply not-up-to-date: it may not have support for SPARQL updates. In that case, contact its developer, or switch to a different PHP library.

**edit** you can of course also just execute SPARQL updates completely "by hand" (so not using any PHP RDF library), just doing a direct HTTP POST operation. For reference, see the [Sesame HTTP protocol documentation](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/system.docbook?view#The_Sesame_REST_HTTP_Protocol), specifically the [section on updating statements](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/system.docbook?view#repository-statements), but roughly, what you'd need to do is this:

1. open a HTTP connection to `http://<host>:<port>/openrdf-sesame/repositories/<repositoryId>/statements` and create a new POST request.
2. set the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
3. add a parameter `update` to the request body with the (form-encoded) SPARQL update string as its value.
4. Fire off the POST request.

If the update was executed normally, you will get a `HTTP 204 NO CONTENT` response.

Comment: But If I want to make SELECT with this library - all works perfect... So... Maybe this library dont know INSERT??

Comment: i tried your way
$sparql = sparql_get( "http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/bp/statements",

 "
 PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
    INSERT DATA{
    <http://example/authorsID>  foaf:written    '".$nazov."' ;
    foaf:label  ".$nazov.".}
 " );



and now its new error... 406: Bad response, 406: No acceptable file format found.

Comment: @miroyeah. Yes, so, as I said in the answer, it probably does not support SPARQL updates.

Comment: great... so, you have any ideas how i can insert this data from php to rdf repository? Any library which can have insert? or any other posibilities?

Comment: That is offtopic for SO, really, but as also remarked in a comment on a previous question by you, I'd recommend taking a look at EasyRDF, which on the face of it is more mature and well-maintained.

Comment: @miroyeah added an alternative way to do this, directly from PHP without the need for extra libraries.